# Set Left & Right Panel width according to Main Panel using Script

Tags: javascript, css

My question is related to CSS & JavaScript.
I have a CSS class (note, its class not ID) named "`main-panel`" and two left and right panels "`left-panel`" and "`right-panel`" - all are classes not IDs and I even can't change class to Id.
Now, what I want I want to set "`min-height`" of "`left-panel`" and "`right-panel`" based on the **"main-panel's" height**.
If after loading the content main-panel's height is 1000px; it should be the min-height of left and right panel.

Comment: Is this height being set in the CSS. ? Do you have control of the CSS? Or is the height being forced by content?

Comment: Height will be depend on the content obviously because its main panel i.e. content DIV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it can be done.

```js
const setPanelHeight = (className, height) => {
  document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].style.minHeight = height;
};

let desiredHeight = getMainPanelHeight();
setPanelHeight("left-panel", desiredHeight);
setPanelHeight("right-panel", desiredHeight);



function getMainPanelHeight() {
  let element = document.getElementsByClassName("main-panel")[0];
  let computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);  
  return computedStyle["height"];
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}

.left-panel,
.right-panel {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main-panel {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-panel"></div>
<div class="main-panel"></div>
<div class="right-panel"></div>
```

Comment: Here you are passing "1000" as parameters - I need to set it with the height of main-panel.

Comment: Fixed code to run based on the main div.

Comment: code is working thanks a lot

Comment: Another issue - I placed script below the ending of the body tag - but after setting these width - one of the comment section is loading after it. so main panel's size is increasing - is there any solution?

Comment: I think jquery may work - as main panel's height increase after loading comments it would automatic increase the left and right panel height?

Comment: Yes, if the size is changing during the lifetime of the page we would need an event attached to detect and recalculate size requirement

Comment: how it will be possible? can you please provide such Jqury